# Framed legend for a combined ErrorListPlot and ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I am struggling to add legends to a combined plot of `ErrorListPlot` and `ListLinePlot`.
Here is the code.

When I tried to add `PlotLegends` to the individuals plots before displaying them on the same plot using `Show`, it did not work as shown in the screenshot attached below. I also tried using `Legended[Show[]]` which did not work as well.

[image]

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
p1 = ErrorListPlot[{{{0.424, 0.555}, 
     ErrorBar[0.02, 0.15]}, {{0.709, 1.06}, 
     ErrorBar[0.015, 0.15]}, {{0.775, 1.33}, 
     ErrorBar[0.015, 0.15]}, {{0.901, 1.48}, 
     ErrorBar[0.015, 0.15]}, {{1.09, 2.16}, 
     ErrorBar[0.015, 0.15]}, {{1.33, 2.51}, 
     ErrorBar[0.015, 0.15]}, {{1.37, 2.48}, 
     ErrorBar[0.015, 0.1]}, {{1.57, 2.69}, ErrorBar[0.015, 0.1]}},
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Medium, PointSize[Medium], "LineOpacity" -> 0.6, 
     Darker[Blue]] ];

p2 = ListLinePlot[{{ \[Pi]/2, 
     2.6130091136816382` }, {1.4707963267948965` , 
     2.571050976016374` }, {1.3707963267948966` , 
     2.451257910107298` }, {1.2707963267948965` , 
     2.268388904666741` }, {1.1707963267948966` , 
     2.0426280363757554` }, {1.0707963267948966` , 
     1.794600396342152` }, {0.9707963267948966` , 
     1.542145438269968` }, {0.8707963267948966` , 
     1.2988682339826867` }, {0.7707963267948966` , 
     1.0738556387461116` }, {0.6707963267948966` , 
     0.8726024301612353` }, {0.5707963267948967` , 
     0.697929615345146` }, {0.4707963267948967` , 
     0.5509379917002875` }, {0.3707963267948966` , 
     0.43163064824113223` }, {0.2707963267948965` , 
     0.3395489795879398` }, {0.17079632679489642` , 
     0.2741253483791365` }, {0.07079632679489634` , 
     0.23498065023767406` }}, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLegends -> "y"];

Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Rebounding velocity (m/s)", 
   "Contact angle \[Theta]"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

Is there any way for me to add legends to the combined plot, one for the `ErrorListPlot` and another one for the `ListLinePlot`, and put the legends in a box inside the final combined graph? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
     Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"Rebounding velocity (m/s)", 
       "Contact angle \[Theta]"}, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14], 
     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
(*Here starts the description of the custom-made legend *)
     Epilog -> 
      Inset[Panel[
        Grid[{{Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.3], Point[{0, 0}]}, 
            ImageSize -> {20, 20}], 
           Style["  Data", 
            14]}, {Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.1], 
             Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, ImageSize -> {20, 20}], 
           Style["  Fitting", 14]}}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
         Spacings -> 0], ImageSize -> {105, 80}], Scaled[{0.8, 0.25}]]
(*Here ends the description of the custom-made legend *)
     ]
```

with the following effect

[image]

It is not difficult to programmatically draw the error intervals in addition to the dot within the legend if needed.

Instead of `Panel` one can use here `Framed` as follows:

```
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Rebounding velocity (m/s)", 
   "Contact angle \[Theta]"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
 (*Here starts the description of the custom-made legend*)
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[
    Grid[{{Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.3], Point[{0, 0}]}, 
        ImageSize -> {20, 20}], 
       Style["  Data", 
        14]}, {Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.1], 
         Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, ImageSize -> {20, 20}], 
       Style["  Fitting", 14]}}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
     Spacings -> 0], ImageSize -> {105, 80}, RoundingRadius -> 5], 
   Scaled[{0.8, 0.25}]]
 (*Here ends the description of the custom-made legend*)
 ]
```

yielding this

[image]

The advantage is the possibility to make rounded corners (if it is the advantage for you).

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the desired legend using [`LineLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html)

```
legend = LineLegend[{Darker @ Blue, Blue}, {"Data", "y"}, 
  Joined -> {False, True}, 
  LegendFunction -> 
     (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5, FrameStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin]] &)]; 

show = Show[p1, p2, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Rebounding velocity (m/s)", "Contact angle θ"}, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14], 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}];
```

and use `legend` and `show` with [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html):

```
Legended[show, Placed[legend, {.8, .25}]]
```

[image]

To place `legend` interactively inside the plot frame, you can use `LocatorPane` with `show` as background and  `legend` as option setting for `Apperance`:

```
LocatorPane[{{1.25, .5}}, show, Appearance -> legend]
```

[image]

**Note:** With this approach you need to create `p1`and `p2` without the option `PlotLegends`. By the way, you need to use `PlotLegends -> {"y"}` to get a legend in your second plot.